# Python basic - renaming files

Tags: python

For example there are 5 files to be renamed, 1 to 1 according to the sequence.

I can do it by putting the names into an Excel spreadsheet and rename them 1 by 1. However I want to learn it from a list way.

I tried the following:

```
import os

l = ['c:\\3536 OK-LKF.txt', 'c:\\2532 PK-HHY.txt', 'c:\\1256 OK-ASR.txt', 'c:\\521 OL-MRA.txt', 'c:\\2514 LP-GRW.txt']

ll = ['c:\\aa.txt', 'c:\\bb.txt', 'c:\\cc.txt', 'c:\\dd.txt', 'c:\\ee.txt']

for a in l:
    for b in ll:
        os.rename(a, b)
```

It doesn't work and only the 1st file is renamed.

What is the right way to do it from list? And is there the risk that the files are renamed, but not in right order?

Comment: You're renaming each item in `a` to every item in `b`. You need to iterate over a list of tuples each of the form `(old_name, new_name)` and do the renaming.

Comment: thanks, Noufal Ibrahim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the nested loop, look at what it does:

```
>>> l = ['c:\\3536 OK-LKF.txt', 'c:\\2532 PK-HHY.txt', 'c:\\1256 OK-ASR.txt', 'c:\\521 OL-MRA.txt', 'c:\\2514 LP-GRW.txt']
>>> 
>>> ll = ['c:\\aa.txt', 'c:\\bb.txt', 'c:\\cc.txt', 'c:\\dd.txt', 'c:\\ee.txt']
>>> for a in l:
...     for b in ll:
...         print('renaming {} to {}'.format(a,b))
... 
renaming c:\3536 OK-LKF.txt to c:\aa.txt
renaming c:\3536 OK-LKF.txt to c:\bb.txt
renaming c:\3536 OK-LKF.txt to c:\cc.txt
renaming c:\3536 OK-LKF.txt to c:\dd.txt
renaming c:\3536 OK-LKF.txt to c:\ee.txt
renaming c:\2532 PK-HHY.txt to c:\aa.txt
renaming c:\2532 PK-HHY.txt to c:\bb.txt
renaming c:\2532 PK-HHY.txt to c:\cc.txt
renaming c:\2532 PK-HHY.txt to c:\dd.txt
renaming c:\2532 PK-HHY.txt to c:\ee.txt
renaming c:\1256 OK-ASR.txt to c:\aa.txt
renaming c:\1256 OK-ASR.txt to c:\bb.txt
renaming c:\1256 OK-ASR.txt to c:\cc.txt
renaming c:\1256 OK-ASR.txt to c:\dd.txt
renaming c:\1256 OK-ASR.txt to c:\ee.txt
renaming c:\521 OL-MRA.txt to c:\aa.txt
renaming c:\521 OL-MRA.txt to c:\bb.txt
renaming c:\521 OL-MRA.txt to c:\cc.txt
renaming c:\521 OL-MRA.txt to c:\dd.txt
renaming c:\521 OL-MRA.txt to c:\ee.txt
renaming c:\2514 LP-GRW.txt to c:\aa.txt
renaming c:\2514 LP-GRW.txt to c:\bb.txt
renaming c:\2514 LP-GRW.txt to c:\cc.txt
renaming c:\2514 LP-GRW.txt to c:\dd.txt
renaming c:\2514 LP-GRW.txt to c:\ee.txt
```

Your program can be fixed by iterating over `zip(l,ll)`:

```
for old, new in zip(l,ll):
    os.rename(old,new)
```

Comment: thanks, timgeb. cool! Can you tell what IDLE you are using? (the one showing the running progress). thanks.

Comment: @MarkK I don't use IDLE, the 'running progress' is shown because I just `print` what happens in your loop.

Comment: oh sorry, I missed to see that..:)

Answer (score 4):

You can use zip

```
for a,b in zip(l,ll):
    os.rename(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rename one to one try this:

```
import os

l = ['c:\\3536 OK-LKF.txt', 'c:\\2532 PK-HHY.txt', 'c:\\1256 OK-ASR.txt', 'c:\\521 OL-MRA.txt', 'c:\\2514 LP-GRW.txt']

ll = ['c:\\aa.txt', 'c:\\bb.txt', 'c:\\cc.txt', 'c:\\dd.txt', 'c:\\ee.txt']

for a in l:
    os.rename(a, ll[l.index(a)])
```